# Как присвоить текст переменной после нажатия на кнопку (Python)

Tags: python

Хочу чтобы ПОСЛЕ нажатия на кнопку можно было ввести какой то текст
Который будет равен с переменной YouTubeUrl

```
def btnYou_press():
    print("Скачать видео с YouTube")
YouTubeUrl = input("YouTube")
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([YouTubeUrl])





root = Tk()
root.title("Assistant")
root.geometry("300x250")

#Кнопка
btn = Button(text="Скачать видео с YouTube",         
             background="#555",     
             foreground="#ccc",     
             padx="20",             
             pady="8",              
             font="16",             
             command = btnYou_press             
             )
btn.pack()
 #Кнопка

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить вторую кнопку, которая вместе с текстовым полем будет отображаться по нажатию первой кнопки. Первая же кнопка после нажатия будет скрываться.

```
import youtube_dl
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text

def btn_hello_handler():
    textBox.pack(padx=5, pady=40)
    btn_hello.pack_forget()
    btn_download.pack()

def btn_download_handler():
    YouTubeUrl = retrieve_input().strip()
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([YouTubeUrl])

def retrieve_input():
    return textBox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')

root = Tk()
root.title("YT downloader")
root.geometry("400x250")


# Кнопка приветствия
btn_hello = Button(text="Скачать видео с YouTube",
             background="#555",
             foreground="#ccc",
             padx="20",
             pady="8",
             font="16",
             command = btn_hello_handler
             )

# Поле ввода
textBox = Text(root, height=2, width=40)

# Кнопка скачивания
btn_download = Button(text="Скачать",
                background="#555",
                foreground="#ccc",
                padx="20",
                pady="8",
                font="16",
                command = btn_download_handler
                )

btn_hello.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо ответ был Мне полезен